# PHP compare is not working

Tags: php

```
$snumber = trim($_POST['sn']);
$site_name =strtoupper(trim($_POST['mn']));
$physical = trim($_POST['pp']);
$logical = trim($_POST['lp']);
$port_info =strtoupper(trim($_POST['ti']));             
$srlt = mysql_query("select subscriber,terminationid from portinfo") or die(mysql_error());

while($wow = mysql_fetch_array($srlt)){
    $suesno =trim($wow["subscriber"]);
    $porting = trim($wow["terminationid"]);  

    if(($suesno == $snumber and $porting == $port_info )){

    }
}
```

the comparison for $suesno and `$snumber` is working. `$suesno` is stored in the database as `6661235`. but the comparison of `$porting` and `$port_info` is not working. and `$porting` is stored in the database as `USER00301500030`

Comment: I can guarantee you that the comparison of PHP works. It must be something in your code. You could try to add an `else` to your `if` statement where you print out all 4 variables. Then you can see what it is trying to compare. Should make it easier to debug.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please be more precise: what exactly does "not working" mean? Does it return a wrong result? For what input, and which output, and what did you expect? Does it generate an error? If so, which? Does it freeze the computer (about the only way possible for it to generate no result *and* no error)?

Comment: ECHO out all 4 variables in your IF and see why it does not match

Comment: There is nothing wrong with my code. The funniest part is that when i change the value of $porting to USER003015 it works fine. or if i change it to number like 123456789000000.

Comment: *"There is nothing wrong with my code. "* ... I beg to differ, e.g.: `mysql_query`

Comment: @LateraTesfaye Works for me: https://3v4l.org/OdsCY - Theres a lot wrong with your code tho. Simply `var_dump()` all the values and compare them, if you still don't find out whats wrong, edit the result of your `var_dump()` into your question.

Comment: _The funniest part is that when i change the value of $porting to USER003015 it works_ Then obviously it is not being set to `USER003015` by your code

Answer (score 0):

try to use && instead of and in if condition

Comment: Because...? Both `and` and `&&` are boolean operators of same semantics, the only thing they differ in is priority, and both have priority lower than `==`. Can you explain how exactly your suggestion solves OP's problem? (And while you're at it, please explain the cause of the problem itself, as it's not very clear to the rest of us.)

Comment: Oops my mistake! the statement in the if statement is true only once for the entire while statement. eventually any declaration of a variable to a true value inside the if statement becomes false. Sorry the problem is not the comparison but my coding!